# Why is a javascript function unaccessible from another script file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I've been searching SO for answers to, but nothing seem to do it for me. I've referenced a question that mimics my problem but the solution still don't solve my problem.

[Accessing function in another .js file with $.getScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595577/accessing-function-in-another-js-file-with-getscript)

My problem is as I've mentioned similar. I can't access a method inside a script file from another script file. These are my codes:

page.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('script.js').done(function () {
        $('#build').append(literals.test()); // $('#build') is a span tag in the HTML-file.
    }).fail(function () {
        console.warn('Unable to load script file.');
    });
});
```

script.js

```
(function ($) {
    var literals = {
            test: function () {
                return 'Hello world!';
            }
        };
})(jQuery);
```

This still returns the following error even though I've built it almost exactly the same way as in the answer of the referenced question.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: literals is not defined at Object.<anonymous>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The symbol `literals` is a **local** variable in that function where it's defined.

Comment: Did you mean to add `literals` to the `window` object instead?

Comment: @Pointy - I think you're up to something here. I'm trying to grasp how I should declare it as a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you create a closure, anything inside of it is only visible to other things in that scope.

In JS, all functions are closures.

```
(function(){
    // this is a closure
})()
```

If you want to be able to get the literals functions from outside of the closure, one option is to return it from the function...

```js
const literals = (function($){
    return {
        test: function () {
            return 'Hello world!';
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

console.log(literals.test());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems as the problem moved one step further: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined.

Comment: I figured it out... I had the 'test' property inside a getScript method... I moved it outside it and now it works fine. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @KristoferGisslén - hit the "run code snippet" button in my answer - it works. make sure you have `script.js` above `page.js`.